# Do apps designed for a different desktop environment (GNOME, XFCE, LXDE, ...) break?

Tags: gui, desktop-environments

Is it true that each app is designed for its own desktop environment (like GNOME, XFCE, LXDE, etc.)? If I try to use an app that's made for a different desktop than I'm using (like using a GNOME app in LXDE), will it break/look ugly or something? I don't get it...

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit better. You have question marks after sentences that sound like statements.

Comment: Hmmm... I have question marks for question sentences. ;)

Comment: It's not clear if "And when I will try to use app that's made for other DE (like Gnome app on LXDE) it will break/look ugly or something?" is a question or a statement. The structure implies it's a statement, mostly because it starts with the word "And".

Comment: I guess you are the only one that have problems with it. You can edit my post, anyway. I don't see need to do it!

Comment: There, the grammar is more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Well generally the answer is 'no'.

A program depends (for instance) on libraries and those libraries get installed with the program. And since those libraries are unique for the desktop environment (DE) they are intended for they will most likely not break the DE you install it on since the maker of said software will try to create unique file names or use general libraries and use general toolkits (and those should be unique too).

If by accident the creator of the program creates something that has the same name and is also saved into the same directory as the software on the DE you want to install it it will get tricky. Sometimes the installer will warn you and quit.

I have seen 1 time where this happend but that was because a piece of software was forked and the person forking it decided to keep names identical instead of actually making it into a new independent program. But you are likely to then choose one over the other so it was basically a non existing problem.

I remember another one: on SCO you have a command called `enable` that has 2 functions: it is part of a printer setup where you `disable` and `enable` a printer. But it also a function for something else (and this one comes first). So you can do `disable /dev/kyo0` but need to do `/usr/bin/enable /dev/kyo0` to enable the printer (this was later fixed by renaming `enable` to `cups-enable`) (from memory so specifics might be off ;) ).
But this is just annoying and was not a big problem: since both reside in different directories the command further up the `PATH` directive needs to have the directory in front of it).

Comment: It seems like you're describing an issue that applies to package management in general, having only a minor connection to the issue of desktop environments. Am I right?

Comment: No you are not correct @Firefeather and are you the one that downvoted me?

Comment: Whoa, Rinzwind, I haven't voted on your answer (up *or* down) at all. I just don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

You really only need to worry about KDE in terms of apps from different desktop environments, and even then, you only need to worry just a little bit. As for Xfce, LXDE, and GNOME, all three of those use the Gimp toolkit (Gtk), so they should function and look properly between each other.

Yes, it might look a bit uglier, but functionality should be retained.

Comment: Could you clarify why you would need to worry about KDE? What does or doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

They might look a bit ugly in some cases, but the functionality will almost always work.